# App structure with Angularjs and UI-Router

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I've been spending the past week learning Angular with an eye to using it in my project. The project is a food-ordering website.

The header and footer are common to all pages/states. The top nav is generated from the categories list (see below). The header will also hold the shopping cart icon and summary, and will also display the user's name when logged in.

There are three levels in the product hierarchy:

- top categories, which will make up the top menu bar
- subcategories, which will show as a menu in the sidebar
- and several dishes/products in each subcategory

The app has these main states:

- Home page with specific content (slider with images, a sidebar with
  various links etc)
- Category page with child subcategories in the sidebar and in the content also with a line-up of the subcategories with a row of products displayed for each.
- the subcategory state can be a child of the category state above, with the same subcategories lined up in the sidebar, but in the content showing all the products from that subcategory, with Add to cart buttons.
- A product can be clicked and then the page content area turns to show a detailed view of that product (large image, ingredients, Add to cart)
- When added to cart, a modal pops up showing a summary of the product that was just added, with total sum that's on the cart, the amount they're still missing to meet the minimum order, and action buttons Continue ordering and Go to checkout
- Yet another state would be the shopping cart page
- Yet another, the signup/login page
- An order summary page
- Of course, the private account area with settings, address, past orders

**Now, my problem is organizing all that in a state structure.**

I have come up with a hierarchy of states with named views, but my main problem is to connect the data from the various views together. For instance, the header view resides in a root state since it's common to all states. But this view needs to have access to several snippets of data, some of which are only available to the other views:

- top menu line-up with the categories. This is generated from a Json array of all categories and subcategories that's resolved from the API upon app load, and also gets used in the sidebar and content views.
- shopping cart summary
- user data when the user is logged in
- this view also needs to mark as active the menu button corresponding to the category that's being accessed. The category id can be passed directly in the URL as in /cat/{id} but is also inferred from the subcategory or product being requested. There will be URLs like /subcat/{id} or /product/{id}. Now, these URL parameters aren't directly available to the root state, but to the states implementing them.

**So the question is, what is the best way to create a repository with all this data?**

It should be accessible from the header, but also from the other views. The solutions I found seem to me more like hacks than proper solutions (things like raising events in order to pass data to the parent state, etc.).

I'm also open to suggestions for the overall organization of the whole app. I'm in the process of learning, so I'm ready to scrape everything and start over. I'm looking to get that assurance that I'm using the best methods for the task. Right now I feel pretty quirky.

So here's what I've done so far:
* Note: I changed the default {{ }} Angular expression delimiters to {[{ }]} because I'm also using Laravel blade.

index.html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="app">
<head></head>

  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div ui-view="header"></div>
    </div> <!-- /container -->

    <div class="container" ui-view="content"></div>

    <div class="container">
      <footer></footer>
    </div> <!-- /container -->
  </body>
</html>
```

app.js:

```js
var app = angular.module('app', ['ui.router', 'ngResource'], function($interpolateProvider) {
        $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('{[{');
        $interpolateProvider.endSymbol('}]}');
    })
    .config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
      $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/home');

      $stateProvider
        .state('root', {
           abstract: true,
           resolve: {
                // A string value resolves to a service
                Config: 'Config',
                // A function value resolves to the return
                // value of the function
                config: function(Config){
                    return Config.query().$promise;
                  }
            },
            views: {
                "header": {
                    templateUrl: "/partials/header.html",
                    controller: function($scope, config, $stateParams){
                        // You can be sure that promiseObj is ready to use!
                        $scope.catsSubcats = config;
                        $scope.catId = $stateParams.catId;
                        $scope.getActiveClass = function (ccsubId,catId) {
                            console.log(ccsubId);
                            if (ccsubId == catId) return 'active'; else return '';
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        })
        .state('root.home', {
            url:'/home',
            views: {
                "content@": {
                    templateUrl: "/partials/home-content.html"
                }
            }
        })
        .state('root.cat', {
            url:'/cat/:catId',
            resolve: {
                // Inject the config resolved in the main state
                // and extract the data we need
                data: function(config){
                  return config;
                }
              },
            views: {
                "content@": {
                    templateUrl: "/partials/cat.html"
                },
                "sidebar@root.cat": {
                    templateUrl: "/partials/cat-sidebar.html",
                    controller: "CatSidebarCtrl"
                },
                "content@root.cat": {
                    templateUrl: "/partials/cat-content.html",
                    controller: "CatContentCtrl"
                }
            }
        })
        .state('root/subcat/:subcatId', {
            url:'/subcat/:subcatId',
            templateUrl:'partials/subcat.html'
        })
    })


app.controller ('CatSidebarCtrl',
    function($scope , $stateParams, data ) { 
        var id = $stateParams.catId;
        $scope.catId = id; 
        //let's get the subcats for the current cat from the cats-subcats Json
        var index;
        var subcats;
        for (index = 0; index < data.length; ++index) {
            if ( data[index].id==id ) subcats = data[index].subcats;
        }
        $scope.subcats = subcats;
    }
);

app.controller ('CatContentCtrl',
    function($scope , $stateParams, data ) { 
        var id = $stateParams.catId;
        $scope.sidebar = id; 
        $scope.ccats = data;
    }
);

app.factory("Config", function($resource) {
  return $resource("/api/cats-subcats");
});
```

cat.html:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-5 col-md-3 sidebar" ui-view="sidebar"></div>

    <div class="col-sm-7 col-md-9 main" ui-view="content"></div>
</div> <!-- row -->
```

cat-sidebar.html:

```
<ul class="nav nav-sidebar">
     <li ng-repeat="sub in subcats"><a href="#">{[{ sub.name }]}</a></li>
</ul>
```

cat-content.html - not done so far